# Cannot get scroll view to scroll with multiple table views in the document view

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am trying this using a Document-Based application.  I'm new to programming, so if I need to use a view-based let me know.  I am trying to create a data entry screen that has one table view as the master, and many more table views as the Details.  I am using interface Builder.  I have embedded all views (master and detail) in a scroll view.  I've also tried embedding all the details views into a box, and embedding that box into a scroll view.  I cannot get any of the tries to scroll.  It "bounces" when I try to scroll and I can see the other table views for a second, but it won't scroll.  I have tried adding constraints and having IB add the constraints.  No combination of constraints or no constraints seems to work.  I have also tried changing the size of the Custom View that holds all the other views and that doesn't work either.  I know I'm missing something simple.  If you need more information, let me know.  Thanks for all suggestions.

**EDIT** to add more detail.

I am using Master-Details for this part of the project.  The goal is to be able to scroll vertically up and down to access all of the nine table views that are part of the Details for the Master Airport Table View.

All of the table views I have work correctly, scrolling as expected inside of the table views.  The trouble occurs with the Details Bordered Scroll View that contains all the text labels, buttons and individual table views.  That Details Bordered Scroll View will not scroll.  In the view hierarchy below it is Bordered Scroll View - Box.

You can see in the view hierarchy I have a Master Table View called Airport Bordered Scroll View - Table View, with the associated labels and buttons separate from the Details table views.

I embedded all the table views, labels and buttons that are part of the Details section of the Master-Details in a Box named Details Box.  Then I tried embedding the Details Box in a Scroll View so I can access every Details Table View, but that didn’t work.  In another build, I tried embedding the Details Table Views and associated buttons and labels into their own scroll view, without the box.  Again, that wouldn’t scroll either.

I'm too new on this site for uploading screen shots, so I think it gives a link to see it.

View Hierarchy:

This is the view hierarchy when I tried using a box around the Details views.

[View hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHN3w.png)

This is what I have built using interface builder.  Again, all of the table views perform normally.

[Interface Builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQyVv.png)

Here is the running app.  You can see that the last table View, HUD Data, is not shown in the screen and I cannot scroll down to see it.

[Window after running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2RDn.png)

The code I have added in Document.swift is mainly for undo and archiving so I don't think it would help here (I could be very wrong though, let me know if so).

I have created separate types for each of the tableViews.  Again, the only code in them so far are the properties and NSCoding protocols.

I can definitely post these if you need to see them.

I used interface builder for every view, label and button so there is no code for them.

Comment: Nested scroll views are confusing, which scroll view will scroll when I use my scroll wheel?. Can you post your code, the view hierarchy and a description of how it should look, scroll and what should happen when the numbers of rows change?

Comment: I have edited and updated the problem above.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you add constraints?

Comment: Yes,  I have tried adding constraints and having IB add the constraints. No combination of constraints or no constraints seems to work.  I can put them back in and add that to the post tomorrow.  It must be something I'm not doing right with the constraints.

Comment: Add constraints so the scroll view resizes with the window and the box doesn't clip its contents.

Comment: I was able to add constraints to the Master Airport control view and I was able to constrain the box/scroll view to its container.  When I try to add any constraint to the table views inside of the box/scroll view, they disappear when I run it, the labels and buttons appear to take the constraints without disappearing.   I tried to constrain the box itself to the scroll view and everything within it was moved out of the entire box and disappeared.  I guess I need to find a book on constraints because I obviously don't understand them.

Comment: Maybe this helps: [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH7-SW1).

Comment: I'll read through that again.  I apparently didn't retain enough.  Thanks Willeke

Comment: I was able to work through this by using your suggestion, Willeke.  I don't know if I should post this as a comment, or answer my own question.  I used the advice of the Auto Layout Guide where it said "In general, use stack views to manage as much of your layout as possible. Resort to creating constraints only when you cannot achieve your goals with stack views alone."  After realizing I needed to organize my table views using stack views, I primarily used the Stack Views section of the Auto Layout Guide and Debugging Auto Layout and I got it to work correctly and scroll like I needed it to.